# How to stop parallel threads

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I want to stop all threads if one of them finished. Something like **Kill-AllThreads**.

PowerShell:

```
workflow Test{
    function writeFile($c, $n){
        $path = "$env:temp\workflow_$n.txt"
        Remove-Item $path -ea 0
        while($true){
            $i++
            "$n-$i"|Out-File $path -Append
            if($i -eq $c){"$n - finished";Kill-AllThreads;break}
        }
    }
    parallel {
        writeFile 5 i
        writeFile 10 k
    }
}

test

start "$env:temp\workflow_i.txt"
start "$env:temp\workflow_k.txt"
```

PowerShell core:

```
((5,'i'), (10,'k'))|ForEach-Object -Parallel{
    $c, $n = $_
    $path = "$env:temp\workflow_$n.txt"
    Remove-Item $path -ea 0
    while($true){
        $i++
        "$n-$i"|Out-File $path -Append
        if($i -eq $c){"$n - finished";Kill-AllThreads;break}
    }
}

start "$env:temp\workflow_i.txt"
start "$env:temp\workflow_k.txt"
```

I expect `i - finished` in console; **i-1..5** and **k-1..5** in file.

Comment: This is possible with [ThreadJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/?view=powershell-7.1) not quite sure if it's possible in a parallel loop.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, here's a way to kill the pipeline depending on the number of outputs (powershell 7).  It creates 10 threads that sleep at random times, then kills the pipe when it receives the output from the first one.

```
1..10 | foreach -parallel { $a = random -max 10 -min 1; sleep $a; $a } | 
  select -first 1

2
```

Comment: `foreach -parallel` != workflow `parallel` statement

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I know, it's powershell 7.